# keep the first 52000 characters of the first line in bash

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I have a big file with many lines and a first line that has something like 100 000 characters.

I'm trying to keep the first 52000 characters from the first line and only the first line **In Addtion** to the rest of the file, which remains the same.

I've search for the net but I only found solutions where the removal of the first n-th characters was the norm.

I thought about `cut -c 1-52000` but `cut` will remove every line and I want only the first line to keep up to 52000 characters.

I checked on `sed` but I did not find something useful.

I thought about this one

`awk '{ NR==1 substr( 1, 52000) } { print }' infile`

Do you think it would work?

Any tips are welcomed.

Comment: It would be helpful to be consistent about the number of characters you need; you've written 52200, 52000, and 50000.

Comment: Do you want to discard lines after the first, or print them unchanged? It's not clear from your question.

Comment: Keith , sorry about that one. 52000. I want to keep the rest of the lines.

Comment: The numbers are still inconsistent; you have 52200 in the title and 50000 in the code snippet. Please update the question.

Comment: Done , Keith. The question has been updated. Good night ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to clip the first line to 52000 characters, and keep the rest of the file unchanged.

**awk**

Your `awk` solution almost works, just change it to:

```
awk 'NR==1 { $0=substr($0, 1, 52000) } 1'
```

The `1` at the end implicitly executes `{ print $0 }`.

**head/tail**

You could also use a combination of `head` and `tail` for this, e.g.:

```
(head -n 1 file | cut -c1-52000; tail -n+2 file)
```

**Testing**

You can test it like this:

```
(printf 123456789; seq 5) > file
```

Testing with `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==1 { $0=substr($0, 1, 5) } 1' file
```

Testing with `head`/`tail`:

```
(head -n 1 file | cut -c1-5; tail -n+2 file)
```

Output in both cases:

```
12345
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: I think the OP just wants the first line extracted, and doesn't care about subsequent lines... not sure though.

Comment: Indeed `Thor` I need the subsequent lines. Cheers for your help.

Comment: @AndyK If you need the subsequent lines, you shouldn't accept anubhava's solution because that only prints the first - surely?

Comment: Indeed, it is not doing what I want.

Comment: `Thor`, your solution is almighty as the nordic god. Cheers for that.

Answer (score 4):

If you're certain that the first line contains more than 52000 characters, you could use `head`.  Saying:

```
head -c 52000 filename
```

would produce the first 52000 bytes from the specified file (note that the specified bytes aren't restricted to the first line).

From `man head`:

```
   -c, --bytes=[-]K
          print the first K bytes of each  file;  with  the  leading  `-',
          print all but the last K bytes of each file
```

Using `head` a variant that would produce the desired result (only from the first line) would be:

```
head -1 filename | head -c 52000
```

Comment: +1, but this only works if you know that there are at least 52k characters on the first line, otherwise it will slurp as many lines as needed.

Comment: Almost , dear `devnull`. I need to keep the rest of the file. So I think your solution with `sed` would work as treat as well.

Comment: Absolutely, this was just meant as a disclaimer for others in the future (and, you know, sometimes people only tell half the truth about their real input data...you never know. Doesn't hurt to mention it.).

Comment: `devnull`, I've put your sed solution and I have this error: `sed: -e expression #1, char 21: Regular expression too big`

Comment: @AndyK I didn't realize that `sed` might choke with massive ranges.  I've added a couple of `head` alternatives that might work for you.

Comment: Cheers for your help, `devnull`

Comment: @AndyK: "I need to keep the rest of the file." -- Then please update your question to make that clear.

Comment: Hi Keith, let me do that.

Answer (score 4):

What about this:

```
dd if=yourfile bs=52000 count=1 2>/dev/null | head -n 1
```

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth Thank you - where can I read about that please?

Comment: It's not [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/head.html) (this affects all kinds of `-<num>`/`+<num>` options for `head`, `tail` and others). Certain `coreutils` versions failed when the environment variable `_POSIX2_VERSION` was set to `2000112` (see e.g. [here](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-utils/2003-08/msg00104.html)) though this was later changed again. Since it's not portable you should refrain from using it. That's also why you won't see it documented in the `coreutils` man pages.

Answer (score 4):

Using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) builtins and `cat` in a command group does exactly what you want:

```
{ IFS= read -r; printf "%s\n" "${REPLY:0:52000}"; cat; } < file
```

- read the first line from stdin
- print the first 52000 chars from that line (or less is the line is shorter - the bash parameter expansion handles that seamlessly)
- cat the rest of the file from sdtin

I'm guessing that since all but the first line of the file is handled by plain old `cat`, then the performance should compare reasonably well with the other answers.

Answer (score 3):

You can use awk:

```
awk 'NR==1{print substr($0, 1, 52000); exit}' file
```

to print only 1st line's 52000 characters.

Comment: Yes but exit is also important here to quit immediately after printing these characters since you are dealing with a huge file.

Comment: +1: Though since you are exiting, `NR==1` is not really needed. `:)`

Comment: You know , folks. I always try my best to come with a solution or at least a good explanation because I know you are reading and I believe in good work. Cheers Everyone ;)

Comment: Dear `Anubhava`, I cannot validate your solution as I need the rest of the file as well `awk 'NR==1 { $0=substr($0, 1, 5) } 1' file`.

I was unclear about that and I'm sorry for that one. I thank you for your help.

Comment: Amazing that this changes the very nature of your question. And even more amazing is that you decided to accept an answer which basically copied from first 2 answers here. Really unbelievable this is.

Comment: Sorry, `Anubhava`. This is the only thing I can say.

Comment: @anubhava My apologies - I did not intend OP to "un-accept" your answer - I was merely seeking clarification of what OP meant as one answerer had interpreted very differently from how you and I did. Apologies.

Comment: @MarkSetchell: No issues but If OP really wanted a change to print all lines instead he could have just edited the question or commented it in any of his previous comments. OP decided to accept a copied answer instead is usually not the general practice on SO. Anyway that is OP's call.

Comment: @anubhava I agree entirely - OPs often accept what I call "sub-optimal" answers! I guess a person who needs to ask a question is not necessarily the ideal candidate for determining the quality of the answers... at least that is what I tell myself sometimes ;-)

Comment: Mark , Anubhava, 

There are 8 answers.

Comment: Yes and you chose the one which was basically a copy of existing answers. It would have been fine if you accepted @devnull's answer since he posted it first.

Comment: Sorry, Anubhava. My answer got cut. 

Without wanting to go into a debate but still with the need to clarify my position, I chose what I think was the best.

True, I should have kept yours and I will do that next time.

I can give you the vote if you want. `Thor` would be unhappy but if you think this is fair, then go for it.

My apologies for my slowness to understand all the tacit rules of this forum.

Comment: I can give you the lame excuse of myself being new but it is not helper and if I messed up, even involuntarly, I take the heat.

Comment: @anubhava: When I read the question the "In Addition to the rest of the file, which remains the same" bit was already there, and I gave a `head`/`tail` answer. Upon further reading I noticed that none of the answers helped the OP do what he wanted with his awk example, so I added that bit to my answer. Perhaps that would have been better placed as a comment or a correction to your answer? This can still be done.

Comment: OP originally wrote: `I'm trying to keep the first 52000 characters from the first line and only the first line.` and that's why mine and devnull's answers were exactly serving that requirement. OP then accepted this answer and later changed the nature of the problem is another matter. Anyway all said & done I don't want to stretch this for long. OP did what he thought was right for him.

Comment: I made a mistake in my formulation , indeed. 

Mistake is mine.

Answer (score 3):

With `perl`:

```
perl -lpe '/^(.{52000})/ and $_=$1 if $.==1' file
```

**or**

```
 perl -lpe '$_=substr($_,0,52000) if $.==1' file
```

Comment: Jaypal, thanks for your help as always. I will run later on that evening as the rest of my script is running late and big boss is behind me. Cheers !

Comment: Thanks @devnull for the tip! I believe OP's requirements got modified so will have to make an update.

Answer (score 0):

Note: This doesn't work. Sed appears to not handle repetition counts greater than 255 characters:

```
sed '1s/\(.\{1,52000\}\).*/\1/'
```

Comment: Looks like @devnull already proposed a very [similar sed solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22839025/2113226), but edited it out due to sed barfing on the "large" regexp

Comment: You're right. The repetition count appears to be limited to 8 bits. At least on Mac OS 10.9.2. I'll leave my answer as a warning.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '1 {s/\(\(\(.\{52\}\)\{100\}\)\{10\}\).*/\1/;}' YourFile
```

Group of group (of group) of repeating count seems to work, but imagine the line if you want 65427 char exactly :-)